# Wrong URL for my custom admin module

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module with a grid in Magento admin panel, it is working perfectly. My doubt is about the URL. For the default Magento module, I am getting the URL as:

```
magento_source/index.php/admin/cms_page/index/key/8b14fb90d8d50c24c0da008db9fd1672/
```

But for my custom module, I am getting the following url:

```
magento_source/index.php/demo/adminhtml_demo/index/key/fc732c9223b88a80ca1b17b2a0f12c95/
```

Instead of

```
magento_source/index.php/admin/adminhtml_demo/index/key/8b14fb90d8d50c24c0da008db9fd1672/
```

What can I do to fix this?

My config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>    
    <modules>
    <Blazedream_Demo>
        <version>1.6.2.0.4</version>
    </Blazedream_Demo>
  </modules>
 <frontend> 
    <routers> 
        <demo> 
            <use>standard</use> 
            <args> 
                <module>Blazedream_Demo</module> 
                 <frontName>demo</frontName> 
            </args> 
        </demo> 
    </routers> 
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <demo>
                 <file>demo.xml</file>
             </demo>
         </updates>
     </layout>
 </frontend>
  <admin>
     <routers>
         <demo>
         <use>admin</use>
         <args>
            <module>Blazedream_Demo</module>
            <frontName>demo</frontName>

        </args>
        </demo>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
<menu>
    <demo module="demo">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
        <children>
            <items module="demo">
                <title>Manage Items</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>demo/adminhtml_demo</action>
            </items>
        </children>
    </demo>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
        <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <demo>
                    <title>Demo Module</title>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                </demo>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <demo>
            <file>demo.xml</file>
        </demo>
    </updates>
</layout>
</adminhtml> 
<global>
    <models>
        <demo>
            <class>Blazedream_Demo_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>demo_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </demo>
        <demo_mysql4>
            <class>Blazedream_Demo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <demo>
                        <table>demo</table>
                    </demo>
                </entities>
        </demo_mysql4>
    </models>
    <events> 
     <demo_save_before>
        <observers>
            <blazedream_demo_save_observer>
               <type>singleton</type>
               <class>demo/observer</class>
               <method>demo_save_before</method>
            </blazedream_demo_save_observer>
        </observers>
    </demo_save_before>
    </events> 
    <resources>
        <demo_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Blazedream_Demo</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </demo_setup>
        <demo_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </demo_write>
        <demo_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </demo_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <demo>
            <class>Blazedream_Demo_Block</class>
        </demo>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <demo>
            <class>Blazedream_Demo_Helper</class>
        </demo>
    </helpers>
 </global>   
 </config>
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add your config.xml code here.

Answer (score 0):

if you use admin router something like below code then it will generate url what you want. this code is get default admin router.

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Simbeez_Ponochange before="Mage_Adminhtml">Simbeez_Ponochange_Adminhtml</Simbeez_Ponochange>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: I have added my config.xml file, can you pls tell me what changes should i do?

Comment: now your router configure as you want now no need to use `demo/.../..`